# Php mktime() return wrong value of hour,minute,second . How to fix?

Tags: php, mongodb, timestamp

I'm using `mktime()` to get timestamp of the input date.
Here is my code:

```
  ` $dayFrom = $this->request->getPost('day-from');
    $monthFrom = $this->request->getPost('month-from');
    $yearFrom = $this->request->getPost('year-from');
    $starttimestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthFrom, $dayFrom, $yearFrom);
    $endtimestamp = mktime(23, 59, 59, $monthFrom, $dayFrom, $yearFrom);`
```

And when i get the result

`$starttimestamp = 1469829600
$endtimestamp = 1469915999`

i try to convert it back using http://www.epochconverter.com/ to check if it is correct but it show `7/30/2016, 5:00:00` for `start time` and `7/31/2016, 4:59:59 AM` for `end time`.

Why is there error with converting the **hours, minutes and seconds** in `mktime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the `date_default_timezone_set`, it may solve your warning and use this code to convert time stamp into readable time  `echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', 1299446702);`